# Exercises to improve my Java programming skills

Tags: java

I have learned basics of Java but want to practice more. I was looking via Google and couldn't find many beginner level problems that I can solve using Java.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What area of programming are you trying to master?

Comment: I'm a generic programmer. stil haven't thought about any specific areas so far. Any suggesstions??

Comment: Do you have any experience with [generic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) in languages other than Java?

Comment: @JayMayu try http://code-exercises.com/programming/, similar to CodingBat but a but nicer interface in my opinion

Comment: Best collections of Java programs- http://java4732.blogspot.in/2015/05/java-programs.html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I recommend reading through the [Sun's tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) for code examples and practice in *all* areas of Java programming, especially the areas you wish to improve in.

Depending on how much of beginner examples you were looking for, check out [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/) for some good beginner exercises. [Project Euler](http://www.projecteuler.net) is another good site, but depending on your skill level now, this may be too much, but it's worth trying anyways.

Most importantly, Its also worth noting that **personal projects** are a great way to start to learn a new language. I would also recommend starting a project that is benefical to you and get cracking right away, no time is better than the present!

Comment: +1 for CodingBat. That thing is super awesome for beginners, and even for advanced programmers, because **you can make your own problems**.

Comment: +1 for CodingBat. Its very nice to get your mindset in programming arena.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney +1 for CodingBat, my wife loves it. :)

Comment: Sun tutorials are a bit obfuscated though.Not recommended for the inpatient.

Answer (score 9):

When learning a new language, there are some nice problem sets you can use to learn the language better.

- [**Project Euler**](http://projecteuler.net/) has some nice problems with a strong mathematical twist.
- Practice on [**Google Code Jam**](http://code.google.com/codejam) past problems, stick to the qualification rounds for the easier problems

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I am obsessed with Project Euler...

Answer (score 8):

I highly recommend reading the book *'Effective Java'* from [Joshua Bloch.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch)

Answer (score 4):

You could try the problems at [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page), many of which lack Java solutions at the moment. The problems are of many different difficulties, but each has a solution already in another language which should help with the algorithmic side.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to learn some GUI, may be tic tac toe is good. Even for console, I still find that is a fun problem. Not challenging but a little bit fun. Later you can advance some other games or port that game to GUI, client server or java applet for the web. I think if you want to learn something and get fun as well, game is a good choice:)

Answer (score 2):

Go and buy the book titled "Java examples in a nutshell". In the book you will find most of practical examples.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to solve problems that you're interested in, writing code that might be useful to you.

Java is a huge box.  It's got a lot of computer science inside: graphics, scientific computing, relational databases, user interfaces for desktop and web, messaging and queuing, multi-threading, security, and more.  Each area has their own "beginner problem".  Which one do you mean?

How do you define "beginner problem"?  Maybe you're having trouble because you aren't narrowing your search enough.

If your imagination is lacking, your best bet is to [Google something like "java beginner practice problems"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+beginner+practice+problems) and investigate what you get back.

Or start with [Sun's on-line Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) and work you way all the way through it.  You'll know a fair amount about Java when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are quite good in Java SE (lets say you are able to pass SCJP), I'd suggest you get junior Java programmer job and improve yourself on real world problems